# Why are records being removed from SQL Table after INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Any ideas why records would disappear from SQL Table after `INSERT` statement? I should mention that the `INSERT` is successful because I can see the records in the table after the `INSERT` statement is executed but then after a short time period (10-30 mins) the added records are deleted. I can confirm that records are being deleted because of an `DELETE` trigger. Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    conn.Open()
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        Dim query as String
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvOrders.Rows.Count - 1
            query = String.Empty
            With comm
                query &= "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TestTemp.dbo.OpenTabs WHERE OrderNum = " & orderNum & " AND " & "ItemNum = " & dgvOrders.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value & ") "
                query &= "INSERT INTO TestTemp.dbo.OpenTabs (OrderNum, CustomerName, UserID, ItemNum, ItemID, Quantity, "
                query &= "                     ItemType, ItemDesc, TransDate, TransTime, ItemPrice, OrderTotal)  "
                query &= "VALUES (@OrderNum, @CustomerName, @UserID, @ItemNum, @ItemID, @Quantity, @ItemType, @ItemDesc, @TransDate, @TransTime, @ItemPrice, @OrderTotal);"
                query &= "UPDATE TestTemp.dbo.OpenTabs SET OrderTotal=" & GetTotal(dgvOrders) & " WHERE OrderNum = " & "@OrderNum "
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = query
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNum", orderNum)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", customerName)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userNameTemp)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNum", dgvOrders.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", dgvOrders.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dgvOrders.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemType", dgvOrders.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemDesc", dgvOrders.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransDate", Today.Date)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransTime", Now)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemPrice", dgvOrders.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderTotal", GetTotal(dgvOrders))
            End With
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            comm.Parameters.Clear()
        Next i
    End Using
    conn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Check for any `SQL Server Agent Jobs` or any `SSIS` package , if it was a Trigger causing this , it would be instant not 10-30 minutes.

Comment: It sounds like the records are being inserted in a transaction, but the transaction is not being committed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please elaborate, I am not familiar with the term a transaction not being committed

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated my question with code

Answer (score 0):

You have some lingering sql injection vulnerabilities in this code (if you don't think numbers can be injected on, try playing with your system's locale settings for negative numbers and currencies). There are a number of other things you can do here to improve this:

```vb
'Use a parameters instead of string concatenation and suddenly you can
'  move the query out of the loop. This could even be a CONSTANT if you wanted.
Dim query As String
query = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TestTemp.dbo.OpenTabs WHERE OrderNum = @OrderNum AND ItemNum = @ItemNum ) " & vbCrLf
query &= "  INSERT INTO TestTemp.dbo.OpenTabs (OrderNum, CustomerName, UserID, ItemNum, ItemID, Quantity, "
query &=          " ItemType, ItemDesc, TransDate, TransTime, ItemPrice, OrderTotal)  "
query &= " VALUES (@OrderNum, @CustomerName, @UserID, @ItemNum, @ItemID, @Quantity, @ItemType, @ItemDesc, @TransDate, @TransTime, @ItemPrice, @OrderTotal);" & vbCrLf
query &= "UPDATE TestTemp.dbo.OpenTabs SET OrderTotal= @OrderTotal WHERE OrderNum = @OrderNum ;"

'Combine the using declarations to reduce code
Using conn As New SqlConnection("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"), _
      comm As New SqlCommand()

    'MUCH better to use explicit types for your parameters.
    ' I needed to guess at the actual column types/lengths here, but you
    ' can check your DB for the actual column definitions.
    'We can also re-use the same parameter objects for each iteration through the loop
    comm.Parameters.Add("@OrderNum", SqlDbType.Int)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemNum", SqlDbType.Char, 15)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Int)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemDesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200)
    'You should REALLY combine these two columns!
    comm.Parameters.Add("@TransDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@TransTime", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ItemPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal)
    comm.Parameters.Add("@OrderTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal)

    Dim Total = GetTotal(dgvOrders)
    'Wait as long as possible to call conn.Open()
    conn.Open()

    'For Each loop instead of For loop means shorter code to use each row value
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvOrders.Rows
        comm.Parameters("@OrderNum").Value = orderNum
        comm.Parameters("@CustomerName").Value = customerName
        comm.Parameters("@UserID").Value = userNameTemp
        comm.Parameters("@ItemNum").Value = row.Cells(4).Value
        comm.Parameters("@ItemID").Value = row.Cells(2).Value
        comm.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = row.Cells(5).Value
        comm.Parameters("@ItemType").Value = row.Cells(3).Value
        comm.Parameters("@ItemDesc").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
        comm.Parameters("@TransDate").Value = Today.Date
        comm.Parameters("@TransTime").Value = Now
        comm.Parameters("@ItemPrice").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
        comm.Parameters("@OrderTotal").Value = Total

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next row
End Using 'No need to call conn.Close(), the Using block **will** take care of this for you
```

To answer the actual question... by default, implicit query batches for Sql Server such as this are committed. You can change this default, but it is very rare to see. Most likely, some code at a higher level from here is **swallowing the exception** produced by the bad sql syntax. This is poor coding practice, so you may want to go track down where.

Comment: Hi Joel, thank you for your answer, I have the missing parenthesis on the first line. and the comma on the second line are is necessary to separate `Quantity` from `ItemType`. I picked up SQL a few weeks ago! I will check if exceptions are being thrown anywhere